# Slideshow is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working with jquery mobile and decided  to use a diashow for pictures. The thing is that the slideshow only works when I am loading the page for a second time.

I am new to jquery mobile and don't quite know how to fix it.

I used the slider from http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VsMVPua6nVI

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>


<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
Slideshow only works by refreshing the page.

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Swiper-master/dist/css/swiper.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Swiper-master/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slidshow.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Swiper-master/dist/js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function diashow() {
            var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', 
            {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                paginationClickable: true
            })        
          });
</script>

</head>
```

Comment: Have you passed any height to your slidehsow's container... something like this would do, .swiper-container {height: 480px;} and of course change it to cater for other various devices, e.g. mobile, tablet if you have... using media queries
hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) with the problem?

Comment: the initialization script is propably not running or has run but nothing to do because of page load init timing -- i bet if you add a few seconds delay inside the document ready to initialize the swiper it will be ok -- other ways will be to move the script at the bottom of the html page --   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: one more thing -- how you load files in the HEAD meaning their sequence is important -- all CSS then all JS files -- or you could move to the bottom of page for some js files so they run after the main js scripts in the head

Comment: one last thing -- it could be also that the images are still loading and causing problems, where the 2nd time works because the images are in the cache and doesnt spend time getting them over the net -- so you can try -- $(window).load -- instead of the --  $(document).ready  -- check here to read about the difference -- http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/document-ready-vs-window-load-vs-window-onload